# Problem binding mouse events

Tags: jquery, mouseevent, unbind

I have a table of images. Each row, when moused over, shows its image in a previously hidden div that's been absolutely positioned. When I mouse over the now shown image, I want to unbind the tr mouseleave events so that the image doesn't flicker, and then rebind the mouseleave events when I leave the image div.

I'm able to unbind the mouseleave event, but rebinding causes the flickering to occur. The relevant code:

```
<table border="1" id="photoTable">
<tbody> 
    <tr class="item">
        <td class="filename">
            GraphDataCAQ3UW88.png
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<div id="thisPhoto"></div>
```

css:

```
#thisPhoto{
display:none;
position:absolute;
left:250px;
top:150px;
border: 1px solid black;
background-color:white;
padding:20px;
z-index:2;
}
```

js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

(function($){
    $.fn.getThisPhoto = function(){
        return $(this).each(function(){
            //I've left out the code which gets the data to pass to $.get()
            $.get('administration/PhotoManagement/thisPhoto.cfm',
                data,
                function(response){
                    $('#thisPhoto').html(response).show();
                }
            );
        });
    };
})(jQuery);

   $('tr.item').hover(function(){       
    $(this).getThisPhoto();
},
function(){
    $('#thisPhoto').hide();
});

$('#thisPhoto').mouseenter(function(){
    $('tr.item').unbind('mouseleave');
}).mouseleave(function(){
    $('tr.item').bind('mouseleave', function(){
        $('#thisPhoto').hide();
    });
});

});
```

EDIT: I hacked it by wrapping the whole shebang in a div and setting mouseout on that div to trigger the hide() and bind() functions... not exactly what I wanted, but it'll do in a pinch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am uncertain whether this model will work for your requirements, but consider making the `div#thisPhoto` into individual `div`s inside your `tr`. This way, while you are moused over the image, you are still moused over the table row. For instance, the markup would be something like:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <div class="thePhoto">
            <img src="http://www.mysite.com/images/Image001.jpg" />
        </div>
        Image001.jpg
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <div class="thePhoto">
            <img src="http://www.mysite.com/images/Image002.jpg" />
        </div>
        Image002.jpg
    </td>
</tr>
```

If you give `div.thePhoto` a `position: relative` style, you can then give the `div.thePhoto > img` a `position: absolute` style and position it relative to the top left corner of the table cell. This way, you only bind a `.hover()` event to each table row to `.find("div.thePhoto")` and display or hide its child `img` element.

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lthibodeaux/UEq6q/) for an example.

Comment: Nice - will give it a try. I'm using the dataTables plugin so am not sure whether the extra divs will break it or not.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to bind and unbind the event, you need to use a different design pattern.

Take a look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Diodeus/gHa4u/1/

Comment: Yes, I thought of that... the only problem with your solution is that you have to make sure you enter the newly shown div in order to close it. Still better than the flickering, though!